# How to load view or use redirect() inside multiple environment check in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, error-handling, environment

Want to check Environment and if matches some case then want to redirect or load some view. `get_instance();` not working inside index.php where environment check

 what i'm looking something like below:

```
if (ENVIRONMENT === "production")
{

    /*if(error ="db error")
    redirect("/someview","refresh");
    or load view header and footer
    */

}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to place your `environment` logic in `index.php` only?

Comment: i just need to redirect when some errors occur. that's all.

Comment: Just to verify, You want to set a common 'error handling logic' to all controllers? Assuming that if in case a `db error` occurred, You would like to redirect it to a certain `view` dynamically? (e.g 'about' => 'home' / 'some-url' => 'home')

Comment: @eeya i just confused about error handling mechanism in CI. By the help of stackoverflow users i found steps to turn off the errors . but now i can't handle those errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i just confused about error handling mechanism in CI. By the help of stackoverflow users i found steps to turn off the errors . but now i can't handle those errors.

If you want to handle a certain error, You can redirect it to a certain view in the process as what you have mentioned in your question.

```
 // Assuming you have a [Home] Controller that extends to your [Common] parent class
 class Home extends Common {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $bCheck = false;
        if ($bCheck !== true) {
            $this->handleRedirectMethod('path/to/your/controller');
        }
    }
}
```

Then on your parent [Common] controller. (e.g Common.php)

```
class Common extends CI_Controller
{
    public function handleRedirectMethod($sUrl, $sMethodName = 'refresh', $sStatusCode = '302')
    {
        $sServerName = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        redirect($sServerName . '/' . $sUrl, $sMethodName, $sStatusCode);
    }
}
```

Hope this makes you understand how you can handle those errors

Comment: I assign $bCheck to false intentionally. From there, you can check your conditions (e.g db error exceptions)

Comment: like code below or not?
$bCheck=$this->db->get($tb);

Comment: Yes, $bCheck = $this->helper->get('tb');. If this returns an error, then call the [redirect] method  from [url] helper class or check the [handleRedirectMethod] illustrated above